# how to convert reverse time for "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a" in android

Tags: java, android

```
private static long converTimeStringINToMillis1(String time) {

    long milliseconds = 0;

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        // 25/06/2014 8:41:26
        Date date;
        date = sdf.parse(time);
        milliseconds = date.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        milliseconds = 0;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return milliseconds;
}

public static String  setLastSeenTime1(String time){

    long milliseconds = Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() -converTimeStringINToMillis(time));

    String lastSeen = "";
    int seconds = (int)milliseconds/1000;
    if(seconds < 60) 
        lastSeen = String.valueOf(seconds) + "sec ago";
    else if(seconds >60 && seconds < 3600)
        lastSeen = String.valueOf((int)seconds/60) + " min ago";
    else if(seconds > 3600 && seconds < 86400)
        lastSeen = String.valueOf((int)seconds/3600) + " hours ago";
    else if(seconds > 86400 && seconds < 172800)
        lastSeen =" Yesterday";
    else if(seconds > 172800 && seconds < 2592000)
        lastSeen = String.valueOf((int)(seconds/(24*3600))) + " days ago";
    else if(seconds > 2592000)
        lastSeen = String.valueOf((int)(seconds/(30*24*3600))) + " months ago";

    return lastSeen;

}
```

This i have apply code for reverse time when time is not 
included am/pm its working fine when i add am/pm  its not working please help where i should change my time is `8/10/2014 8:54:10` Pm in this format i have to apply reverse time from current time

Comment: I'm not fluent in Java so I won't post an answer, but from what I understand, your problem is happening when you append a string ("am/pm") to the Date/Time, thereby converting the entire Date/Time to a String. To counter this you would have to extract the Date/Time portion of the new string using `substr` and do the calculation on that. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Change Caps **HH** to small **hh**

Caps HH will return 24 hrs format

Small hh will return 12 format

Change this..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

Comment: still not working my time is coming 8/10/2014 8:54:10 Pm system time is 8:11:2014 10:13:54 Am  result of revrese time is coming 8 days agao

Comment: while it should display 1 days agao